# How to move QWidget in QAbstractItemView?

Tags: qt

I have a QComboBox, which has many items on it:

```
    combo->addItem("def");
    combo->addItem("abc");
```

Now I would like to add QWidget to one of my item, for example:

```
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background:red}");
    button->setFixedSize(10,10);
    QModelIndex index = combo->model()->index(0,0);
    combo->view()->setIndexWidget(index, button);
```

I set button's size to 10x10 ( of course my QComboBox is bigger ). And I would like to move this button to other place ( picture ).

[image: Picture]

Comment: It is designed so, that the widget should take the whole space in the cell. On the other side, with `button->setFixedSize(10,10);` you restrict it to 10 pixels in width and height, so the widget "hangs" in the top left corner. That, what you are trying to do, is achieved through delegates. However, to give you a more specific answer, more details about the desired behavior should be shared.

Comment: @user6528273 Thank you for answer. I agree with you that I should use delegates, but I don't have idea how. This is my whole code ( only create QComboBox, add items to it, create QPushButton, set its size, add button to combo->view() ).

Comment: This is your code, but not your intention. How should this function, Describe your use case.

Comment: @user6528273 I would like to remove item from QComboBox when I click on QPushButton. I have to use QComboBox ( no QListWidget ).

Comment: Then let me try to put something together for you.

Comment: @user6528273 Do you have any idea, Sir?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, the API of `QComboBoxDelegate` is private, which makes the solution very ugly. Do you insist on using `QComboBox`, or a combination of `QLineEdit` + `QListView` would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using layout

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background:red}");
button->setFixedSize(10,10);

auto widget = new QWidget{this};
auto layout = new QHBoxLayout{widget};
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
layout->addStretch();
layout->addWidget(button);

QModelIndex index = combo->model()->index(0,0);
combo->view()->setIndexWidget(index, widget);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I just did. Have to change the margins a bit and add a missing semicolon, but that's it.